# How do I remember my selection with the press of a done button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am using checked views in my list. I have 2 toggle buttons,which when clicked update the UI. i want to make my code such that it remembers the previously selected value and if it remains the same done button is disabled and if it is changed ,say I switch to value 2, done button is enabled and vice versa and also it remembers my previous selection when I return to the same view later. Here's is my code for the same:

```
 public class ManageListDashboardFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnCheckedChangeListener {
        public final static String TAG_MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT = "ManageListDashboardFragment";
        private boolean mIsPersonal = true;
        private boolean mIsShared = true;

        private boolean mShouldbeon;
        private boolean mInitialShouldbeon;
        private boolean mShouldbeon1;
        private boolean mInitialShouldbeon1;
        protected Button mPreferencesDoneButton;
        final boolean isPersonal = true;
        final boolean isShared = true;
        private ListsFragment mListsFragment;
        ToggleButton one; 
        ToggleButton two;
        public static ManageListDashboardFragment newInstance(final FragmentManager manager, final int animation) {
            final ManageListDashboardFragment fragment = new ManageListDashboardFragment();
            final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ANIMATION, animation);
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD, R.id.manage_news_categories_container);
            fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT);
            FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_lists, container, false);
            final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
            final int animation = arguments.getInt(ANIMATION, 0);
            final ManageListDashboardActivity activity = (ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity();
            if (animation != 0) {
                activity.animateTitle(R.id.actionbar_title, arguments.getInt(ANIMATION, 0));
            }
            return view;
        }
        protected void setupClickListeners() {
            mIsPersonal = isPersonal;
            mPreferencesDoneButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_done);
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(mPreferencesDoneButton.getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/proxima-nova-regular.ttf");
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setTypeface(face);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(((ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity()).isDoneButtonEnabled());
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            final TextView titleView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
            titleView.setText(R.string.manage_dashboard_lists);

            initManageListDashboardFragment();

        }

        private void initManageListDashboardFragment() {
            populateData();
            setupClickListeners();

            Button personalbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_personal_list);
            personalbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
            Button sharedbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_shared_list);
            sharedbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
            one = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.personal_list_toggle_control);
            one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            two = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.shared_list_toggle_control);
            two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        }
        protected void populateData() {
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().updateIsUserPreferencesUpdated(false);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final ManageListDashboardActivity activity = (ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity();

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_personal_list:
                    mIsPersonal = !mIsPersonal;
                    mIsShared = false;
                    one.setChecked(mIsPersonal);
                    return;

                case R.id.button_shared_list:
                    mIsPersonal = false;
                    mIsShared = !mIsShared;
                    two.setChecked(mIsShared);
                    return;


                case R.id.button_done:
                    saveUserPreferences();

                    DashboardFragment.getInstance().getListsFragment().setIsPersonal(mIsPersonal);

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            activity.onBackPressed();
        }
        private void saveUserPreferences() {

            final SharedPreferencesManager manager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance();
            if (manager.shouldManageListDashboard() == mIsPersonal) {
                manager.shouldManageListDashboard();
            }


        }


        protected void toggleDoneButton() {
            boolean isUserPreferencesUpdated = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().isUserPreferencesUpdated();
            boolean isDoneEnabled = (
                     mShouldbeon != mInitialShouldbeon || mShouldbeon1 != mInitialShouldbeon1
                    || isUserPreferencesUpdated);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(isDoneEnabled);
        }
        public void onUpdate() {
            mListsFragment.onUpdate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                 if (buttonView == one) {
                        two.setChecked(false);
                    }
                 else if (buttonView == two) {
                        one.setChecked(false);

                    }
                }
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
                case R.id.personal_list_toggle_control:

                    mShouldbeon = isChecked;
                    if(mShouldbeon = isChecked && mShouldbeon1 != isChecked){


                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.shared_list_toggle_control:

                    mShouldbeon1 = isChecked;
                    if(mShouldbeon1 = isChecked && mShouldbeon != isChecked){
                        }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            toggleDoneButton();
        }

    }
```

Comment: any example with respect to my code?

Comment: Forget it, I didn't read the question properly.  Detention for me!  Sorry.  Let me try again.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I am just trying to save the selected values in my fragment somehow. Say I have button 1 and button2 with toggle buttons. By default I want button 1 to be selected and done button disabled, until I change the selection by selecting button 2, then done button gets enabled and upon clicking that it saves the selected button value (say button2 to true in my case). and the cycle repeats when I return to this view where now I would see button2 selected and button 1 unselected and done button disabled until I change my selection

Comment: When toggle button 1 is checked, you can dynamically change the xml's default value of toggle button 2 and then redraw your fragment. Probably not the most efficient way, but I believe it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to create a 2 static variables in your ManageListDashboardFragment to save the current state of your togglebuttons. Update those variables when done button is pressed. And in your initManageListDashboardFragment() update the state of your toggle button according to current values of static variable. Of course, the static variable value would be preserved only as long as your app is running. If you want your states to be preserved even on different instances of your app then use SharedPreference instead of static variables.

Example of SharedPreferance:-

```
public class ManageListDashboardFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public final static String TAG_MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT = "ManageListDashboardFragment";
    private boolean mIsPersonal = true;
    private boolean mIsShared = true;
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private boolean mShouldbeon;
    private boolean mInitialShouldbeon;
    private boolean mShouldbeon1;
    private boolean mInitialShouldbeon1;
    protected Button mPreferencesDoneButton;
    final boolean isPersonal = true;
    final boolean isShared = true;
    private ListsFragment mListsFragment;
    ToggleButton one; 
    ToggleButton two;
    public static ManageListDashboardFragment newInstance(final FragmentManager manager, final int animation) {
        final ManageListDashboardFragment fragment = new ManageListDashboardFragment();
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ANIMATION, animation);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD, R.id.manage_news_categories_container);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_MANAGE_NEWS_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_lists, container, false);
        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        final int animation = arguments.getInt(ANIMATION, 0);
        final ManageListDashboardActivity activity = (ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity();
        if (animation != 0) {
            activity.animateTitle(R.id.actionbar_title, arguments.getInt(ANIMATION, 0));
        }
        return view;
    }
    protected void setupClickListeners() {
        mIsPersonal = isPersonal;
        mPreferencesDoneButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(mPreferencesDoneButton.getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/proxima-nova-regular.ttf");
        mPreferencesDoneButton.setTypeface(face);
        mPreferencesDoneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(((ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity()).isDoneButtonEnabled());
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final TextView titleView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
        titleView.setText(R.string.manage_dashboard_lists);

        initManageListDashboardFragment();

    }
    Button sharedbutton;
    Button personalbutton;
    private void initManageListDashboardFragment() {
        populateData();
        setupClickListeners();
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());


        personalbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_personal_list);
        personalbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        sharedbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_shared_list);
        sharedbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        one = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.personal_list_toggle_control);
        one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        boolean toogle = sp.getBoolean("toggle", true);
        two = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.shared_list_toggle_control);
        two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        if(toogle) {    
        one.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
        two.setChecked(true);
        }

    }
    protected void populateData() {
        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().updateIsUserPreferencesUpdated(false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        final ManageListDashboardActivity activity = (ManageListDashboardActivity) getActivity();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_personal_list:
                mIsPersonal = !mIsPersonal;
                mIsShared = false;
                one.setChecked(mIsPersonal);

                sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", mIsPersonal).commit();
                return;

            case R.id.button_shared_list:
                mIsPersonal = false;
                mIsShared = !mIsShared;
                two.setChecked(mIsShared);
                sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", !mIsShared).commit();
                return;


            case R.id.button_done:
                saveUserPreferences();

                DashboardFragment.getInstance().getListsFragment().setIsPersonal(mIsPersonal);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        activity.onBackPressed();
    }
    private void saveUserPreferences() {

        final SharedPreferencesManager manager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance();
        if (manager.shouldManageListDashboard() == mIsPersonal) {
            manager.shouldManageListDashboard();
        }


    }


    protected void toggleDoneButton() {
        boolean isUserPreferencesUpdated = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().isUserPreferencesUpdated();
        boolean isDoneEnabled = (
                 mShouldbeon != mInitialShouldbeon || mShouldbeon1 != mInitialShouldbeon1
                || isUserPreferencesUpdated);
        mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(isDoneEnabled);
    }
    public void onUpdate() {
        mListsFragment.onUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked){
             if (buttonView == one) {
                    two.setChecked(false);
                    personalbutton.setEnabled(false);
                    sharedbutton.setEnabled(true);
                    one.setEnabled(false);
                    two.setEnabled(true);
                    sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", true).commit();
                }
             else if (buttonView == two) {
                    one.setChecked(false);
                    personalbutton.setEnabled(true);
                    sharedbutton.setEnabled(false);
                    two.setEnabled(false);
                    one.setEnabled(true);
                    sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", false).commit();
                }
            }
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.personal_list_toggle_control:

                mShouldbeon = isChecked;
                if(mShouldbeon = isChecked && mShouldbeon1 != isChecked){


                }
                break;
            case R.id.shared_list_toggle_control:

                mShouldbeon1 = isChecked;
                if(mShouldbeon1 = isChecked && mShouldbeon != isChecked){
                    }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        toggleDoneButton();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to use sharedpreferences, but not sure how to .Can you explain with code for my case?

Comment: thanks! That worked for toggle 2 and toggle 1, but as soon as I save toggle 1 the app crashes, and by default its supposed to show toggle 1 clicked when u first launch the app (later on shared prefs will take care of it) , is there any way I can set it to toggle 1 on first launch without making checked:true in the xml ,so that i can have dynamic behavior?

Comment: Yes in initManageListDashboardFragment() change one.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("toggle1", false)); to one.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("toggle1", true));

Comment: So, even if that works initially , it crashes as soon as I toggle. I think there must be some condition set in the init, so it doesn't recognize one as true and one as false everytime an init is called. I think there must be a way so if only one is set to true (and saved in sharedprefs) two will be false and vice versa. does that make sense?

Comment: as soon as I comment out // one.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("toggle1", true)); , it works without crash, but doesnt save toggle1 prefs,only toggle 2 when selected. However if i save it, something causes a null pointer exception and it crashes for toggle 1

Comment: I am gettign this crash:  E/AndroidRuntime(7625): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(7625):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
0 E/AndroidRuntime(7625):  at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(ToggleButton.java:73)
everytime i save toggle 1, like it's trying to override something, just for toggle 1 though

Comment: Ok i will update the code that uses one preference instead of two

Comment: I have updated my answer which uses only one preferance. Now initManageListDashboardFragment() will always set one and two compliment to each other

Comment: as soon as i save toggle1, something causes issue and it crashes, but as soon as I comment this line out one.setChecked(toogle); it works without crash ,however it doesnt show toggle1 as saved( shows both unchecked)

Comment: No issues, I just set android:checked="true" back in xml and seems to work fine with that bit commented out for one.setchecked. However I see when the same button is tapped twice it unchecks the button instead of keeping it the same,unless another button is touched. Is there a way I can detect two taps/touches and keep it intact and give it the behavior of a proper toggle radio button

Comment: that works fine, but I am still able to untap both checks instead of a radio like behavior where one of the 2 buttons has to be active at a time and if preferences are unchanged done button is disabled. something in my code is wacky and shows the done button disabled only when toggle button 1 is saved but not for toggle button 2

Comment: So you want to disable toggle button once its checked value becomes false and enable another toggle button which has checked value true?

Comment: First if I have button 1 checked and button 2 unchecked and I click on button 1 , it should stay checked and not make the check disappear completely and vice versa. Apparently I am able to  uncheck both the buttons simultaneously without even toggling but touching twice. Also, for the second part. If say I have button 1 selected and then I tap on done button then I return to the view and until I change my selection to button 2 the done button needs to be shown disabled, but in my case it shows enabled even if the selection hasnt changed :(

Comment: I have made changes. Now I think you should not be able to double tap

Comment: I am still able to double tap it.Tried placing it on onclick aswell ,no luck, even tried setclickable on checkchanged but no luck

Comment: Are you double tapping buttons (button_personal_list and button_shared_list) or togglebuttons (personal_list_toggle_control and shared_list_toggle_control) ? Also is there any special reason for the need of separate buttons as you can simply use togglebuttons which you already have for that purpose?

Comment: I am able to toggle back and forth. Only thing is suppose if button 1 is checked and if I tap there again it will remain checked which is the expected behavior. In my case I am not only able to toggle (as expected) but also able to individually uncheck each button without toggling which is causing issues

Comment: I have created toggle control buttons to enable and disable the done button accordingly, but this logic might not be right, might need just one of those cases i guess

Comment: even after commenting out that code block for personal toggle control, i can still double tap the buttons one and two

Comment: See if updated code works as now i have even disabled buttons

Comment: do you have any idea about this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013926/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-my-last-selected-item-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment35153663_23013926